# How to move up 2nd page margin to top in Crystal Report Cross tab

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I build report by using cross tab in crystal report in the first page i have title page that take area about 1/4 of the page consist with logo and report name and filter detail    So on the second page it shown up the same position as the first page   something that I want is to remove the report header section and move up the page header section and detail section to top on the 2nd page   Thanks you for answer and i want to know   Is this need to do ?? because some aspect of user tell that Its' okay don't move 2nd page up its should be like this same position same line  its easy to read and compare the pages            some aspect think that it's lost the area of the head of page 2 it's useless what should I do from here

To cojimarmiami,
i tried your suggestion formula but it' doesn't work   when i preview it show just a page in horizantal by the vertical space separate it for 2 Block  (not page)  and when i printed its' come out 2 pages in A4 paper  What should i do for the next step Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you will have to place your `logo, report name and filter` on `Page Header`, then go to that `Section Expert` and place this formula on `Suppress` `pagenumber <> 1`. That is going to suppress that section if your are not on the first page.